# Does "always" also mean "all" when used without other "modifying" terms

Tags: grammar, differences

I was reading a rather popular [tweet](https://twitter.com/kumailn/status/958025600828030976) and possibly got completely sidetracked with a language issue.

> Art has always been political.
>   Music has always been political.
>   Movies have always been political.
>   Books have always been political.
>   [...]

Here, I understand that according to the author's viewpoint, art, in its every forms, at any current or passed time, has been political. That is, that every expression of art, is political.

In the comments, there was some arguing that no, it doesn't mean that, only that *some* art is. However, from the absence of any other words around it, I'd argue that in english, if we remove cultural viewpoint as to what words means, a sentence like "the sky is blue" or "music has always been political" means that the sky is always blue everywhere and that every music is political everywhere.

For instance, if we were to say "Shostakovich's music has always been political", there would be a difference.

Does always also mean all, everywhere, at anytime?

Comment: To me it definitely means "At least some art has always been ..." rather than "All art has always been ..." but that's just my opinion; I'm not sure there is an "official" answer.

Comment: Since the interpretation as "all art everywhere at any time is political" is clearly false, but the interpretation as "at no time has there NOT been some political art" is reasonable and probably true, I think it's justifiable to assume that the more reasonable version is the intended meaning.

Comment: 'If we remove cultural viewpoint as to what words mean[]' isn't what natural languages are about.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Heh, point taken. I guess some part of me wishes there was a simple "true" interpretation of meaning, in accordance to some generally agreed upon rules of language...

Comment: There's a whole branch of linguistics called 'pragmatics'. @Hellion has shown how this would be applied here. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) has a good article on this.

Comment: @Hellion It [that pragmatic viewpoint, if I can call it that] also sounds like a fine way to stay sane on the internets. Thanks for that.

Comment: I think OP is being tempted to misinterpret ***always*** as meaning *in all the different ways something occurs* (in all its forms). But actually today it *always* means ***throughout all time***.

Comment: The meaning I am perceiving is 'Throughout history, art has tended to be political'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author wrote:

> Art has always been political.
>   Music has always been political.
>   Movies have always been political.
>   Books have always been political.

The author did not write:

> All art has always been political.
>   All music has always been political.
>   All movies have always been political.
>   All books have always been political.

So, I think we can keep a traditional definition of [always](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/always) without any problem understanding a generalization is being made.

> I have  *always* enjoyed pizza

does not mean I enjoyed the odd pizza that had dead fish (anchovies) on it. I have no use for dead fish.
I can say

> I have *always* enjoyed pizza

without meaning

> I have *always* enjoyed any pizza.

Pizza, art, music. movies and books are general concepts, with many possible components.  I'm sure the author did not intend for *always* to be applied to any and all specific parts of those concepts. Had he so intended, he would have articulated "all parts" of the concept, not just the generalization.

Comment: Oh well. It took only a few months for me to get over myself, but I guess I must say that this interpretation is indeed the most valid one. Thanks for that.